# Could not perform immediate configuration on 'multiarch-support'

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

I am not sure what I was thinking when I accidently deleted my `/etc/dpkg/` folder. While I was fixing that, I tried many things and that made things worst. Now I am in a situation where I can not install or remove anything on my server. 
When I try to run something, it ends up on following message:

> E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'multiarch-support'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)

I have tried everything I could :( Can someone please guide me here? Server is debian 6.0
I can not install a fresh copy because I am using ispconfig to manage many domains and there is no way to backup that so I can install a fresh copy and restore stuff without doing a lot of work again.

**Server Response:**
Linux ispconfig.baskemus.com 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 00:26:11 UTC 2013 x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
ispconfig# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

The following NEW packages will be installed:

adduser apt apt-utils base-files base-passwd bash bash-completion bsdmainutils bsdutils ca-certificates coreutils dash dbus debconf debconf-i18n debian-archive-keyring debianutils diffutils dmsetup dpkg e2fslibs e2fsprogs findutils gawk
  gcc-5-base gnupg gnupg-curl gpgv grep gzip hostname init init-system-helpers initscripts insserv krb5-locales libacl1 libapparmor1 libapt-inst1.7 libapt-pkg4.16 libattr1 libaudit-common libaudit1 libblkid1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc6
  libcap-ng0 libcap2 libcap2-bin libcomerr2 libcryptsetup4 libcurl3-gnutls libdb5.3 libdbus-1-3 libdebconfclient0 libdevmapper1.02.1 libexpat1 libfdisk1 libffi6 libgcc1 libgcrypt20 libgmp10 libgnutls-deb0-28 libgpg-error0 libgpm2
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libhogweed4 libidn11 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkmod2 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5 libmount1 libmpfr4 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnettle6 libp11-kit0 libpam-cap
  libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libpcre3 libprocps4 libreadline6 librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libseccomp2 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1
  libsigsegv2 libsmartcols1 libss2 libssh2-1 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libtasn1-6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl libtinfo5 libudev1 libusb-0.1-4 libustr-1.0-1 libuuid1 login lsb-base mount
  multiarch-support ncurses-base ncurses-bin openssl passwd perl-base procps psmisc readline-common sed sensible-utils startpar systemd systemd-sysv sysv-rc sysvinit sysvinit-utils tar tzdata udev util-linux uuid-runtime zlib1g
0 upgraded, 143 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/47,5 MB of archives.

After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'multiarch-support'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)

ispconfig#

Comment: Post the complete trace, starting with the command you ran, and including all error messages. Most systems can run without a `/etc/dpkg` at all, so that is probably not the source of your problem — rather, it would be one of the many unspecified things you tried.